# Creating custom CodingKey Object in Swift

Tags: swift, codable

I'm trying to do something a little custom with my `Codable` objects. My JSON objects use several types of tokens, so I'd like to make them type safe. To do that, I've created the following Codable classes:

```
class Token: Codable {
    let value: String

    init(_ value: String = "") {
        self.value = value
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()

        value = try container.decode(String.self)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()

        try container.encode(value)
    }
}

extension Token: Equatable { }
extension Token: Hashable { }

class UserToken: Token { }
class ProductToken: Token { }
// etc...

struct User: Codable {
    let token: UserToken
    let friends: [UserToken : User]
    // ...
}
```

JSON Objects:

```
// User
{
    "token":"12345",
    ...
}
```

This works great, except for the case where these tokens are used as keys in a dictionary like so:

```
// User
{
    "token":"12345",
    "friends":{
        "56789":{ // User
            "token":"56789",
            ...
        },
        "09876":{ // User
            "token":"09876",
            ...
        }
     }
}
```

To get this working, I've updated my `Token` class to conform to `CodingKey` (seems to be the right thing to do):

```
class Token: Codable, CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String {
        return value
    }

    var intValue: Int? {
        return Int(value)
    }

    required init?(stringValue: String) {
        value = stringValue
    }

    required init?(intValue: Int) {
        value = "\(intValue)"
    }

    // Plus above implementation
}
```

This does not seem to work properly though, failing with the following error. Looks like the JSONDecoder thinks it should be decoding an array instead of a dictionary... Is this a bug in Codable?

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Comment: You are supposed to add an enum that implements `CodingKey` to your class , see [this article from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) for an explanation (scroll down a bit). And you shouldn't need to implement `init(from encoder:)` or `decode(from:)`

Comment: I do need to implement `init(from encoder:)` and `decode(from:)` because, if you look closely, you'll see I'm replacing the String with my `UserToken`, as opposed to the string being a value in another JSON object (I'm inserting my UserToken type between the User object and the String token).

Comment: Please show a 'struct User' declaration, especially 'friends' member declaration. It should be Dictionary.

Comment: The struct User is defined below the tokens. I’ve updated it to include the friends dictionary, keyed by UserToken.

Comment: JSON keys are required to be `String`. `Token` is not a string. For any customization you have to write code.

Comment: In JSON, the key would still be a string. I just want the key to be `UserToken` in my code. To be clear, this concept of wrapping a string in a type safe object works perfectly in all other cases, except when the string is a key in a dictionary.

Comment: As I said, of course you can use it but you need to write the code to map the object to a string and vice versa.

Comment: Yeah that’s what I ended up going with. But I never found anything explicitly indicating what I’m looking for is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I can get to something clean is the following:

First, extend `KeyedDecodingContainer` (`Token` conforms to `CodingKey`):

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {

    func decodeTokenContainer<TokenKey, Value>(keyedBy tokenKeyType: TokenKey.Type,
                                               valueType: Value.Type,
                                               forKey key: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key) throws -> [TokenKey : Value] where TokenKey: Token, Value: Decodable {
        let tempDict = try nestedContainer(keyedBy: tokenKeyType, forKey: key)

        var tokenDictionary = [TokenKey : Value]()
        for key in tempDict.allKeys {
            let value = try tempDict.decodeIfPresent(Value.self, forKey: key)
            tokenDictionary[key] = value
        }
        return tokenDictionary
    }
}
```

Then, you need to override the decode/encode methods of the containing class:

```
struct User {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        ...

        friends = container.decodeTokenContainer(keyedBy: UserToken.self, 
                                                 valueType: User.self, 
                                                 forKey: .friends)
    }
}
```

If anyone has a solution where I don't need to do this on the `User` object, that'd be great. I have a lot of objects with a lot of properties that I'd have to manually implement the encode/decode methods for.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
struct User: Codable {
    let token: Token
    var friendsList: [Friend] {
        get { return friends.friends }
        set { friends.friends = newValue }
    }
    private var friends: FriendsList
    
    
    private struct FriendsList: Codable {
        var friends: [Friend]
        
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            
            let dictionary = try container.decode([String: Friend].self)
            
            var friends = [Friend]()
            _ = dictionary.map { (_, value: Friend) in
                friends.append(value)
            }
            self.friends = friends
        }
        
        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            
            var dectionary = [String: Friend]()
            _ = friends.map { friend in
                dectionary[friend.token.value] = friend
            }
            try container.encode(dectionary)
        }
    }
}


struct Friend: Codable {
    let token: Token
}


class Token: Codable {
    let value: String

    init(_ value: String = "") {
        self.value = value
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()

        value = try container.decode(String.self)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()

        try container.encode(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: This turns the dictionary into an array, I'd like to keep it as a dictionary.